# Change mouse pointer position at boot or reset center position

Tags: boot, 18.04, mouse, dell, reset

I have the most futile question but it drives me crazy.

I am on 18.04, Dell XPS 9550. Since the beginning of time, at boot, the mouse pointer was in the middle of the screen, hovering on my username.

From the other day, I have no idea why, Ubuntu boots up with the pointer in the lower right corner.

Is there an easy way to put it back in the middle of the screen?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it something the BIOS is deciding, there are no apparent solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Found at: https://linuxconfig.org

As a privileged administrator user use your text editor to perform the following changes of the GDM3 custom configuration file /etc/gdm3/custom.conf.

FROM:

```
# WaylandEnable=false
```

TO:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

By uncommenting the above line your system will use the Xorg display manager instead of Wayland next time it boots.

Reboot your system to apply the changes. This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks but it did not worked. By rebooting in Xorg, the mouse pointer was still in the lower right corner.

Comment: I switched from Ubuntu to elementary OS and funnily enough, at boot the mouse is still there in the lower right. I believe BIOS is deciding about it.