# Mouse starts at bottom right at login and boot instead of center

Tags: boot, login, mouse

I have a dual boot system (Ubuntu 18.04.3) on my laptop. Currently when booting to ubuntu, the cursor starts on the bottom right instead of at the centre. When logged in, the cursor sets itself to the same (or similar) bottom right. I do not see this issue in Windows 10 where the cursor starts at the centre and does not set itself upon login.

I am aware that a part solution is to use `xdotool` and can be seen [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/792911/how-to-set-cursor-position-with-command-script) but that only works for the account of the user.

What I want to do is be able to permanently set the cursor to start in the centre of the screen at boot.

Comment: Duplicate question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057161/change-mouse-pointer-position-at-boot-or-reset-center-position

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change mouse pointer position at boot or reset center position](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057161/change-mouse-pointer-position-at-boot-or-reset-center-position)

Comment: Mentions no apparent solution. I don't know if it helps but I am not using any Dell laptop. I am using a surface book 2 laptop.